# C extract number from a string

Tags: c

I would like to extract a number from string using sscanf.

the number is between "=" and ";"

```
 #include <stdio.h>

    int main() {
      char name[20];
      int id;
      sscanf("tabid=12544787844;123", "%[^=]=%d", name, &id);
      printf(" name = %s id=%d\n", name ,id);
      return 1;
    }
```

i got the following result :

> name = tabid id=-340114044

what is wrong with the regular expression of sscanf

Comment: 12 bln. doesn't fit in 4 bytes

Comment: Just for the records: a `scanf()` format string is **not** a regular expression.

Comment: I assume in your final code, the input won't be hardcoded, so `%[^=]` is a **buffer overflow waiting to be exploited** -- use `%19[^=]`.

Comment: I'd drop `sscanf` alltogether, parse the string myself and use [`strtoll`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) to convert the strings to numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`12544787844` doesn't fit into `int` since it's bigger than `INT_MAX` (so you get an overflow). Use `long long` with `%lld` format string.

Comment: Which is btw one of the many reasons not to use `scanf()` in the first place: No way to detect this reliably. But that's out of scope here, so, good answer.

Comment: @Dan I changed the variable type to long long but I cant not get the right value of the number !!

Comment: @Anis_Stack because you also need to change your format string to `"%[^=]=%lld"` and in `printf` too (`" name = %s id=%lld\n"`).

Answer (score 0):

The posted code contains a few problems, as covered in the comments to the question.

The following proposed code:

1. properly formats the 'format string for the call to `sscanf()
2. properly declares the ID variable to be large enough to hold the ID
3. properly checks for errors
4. indents the code for readability
5. for your assistance, documents why each header file is included
6. eliminates the 'magic' number by giving it a meaningful name
7. notice the `;123` is never input

And now, the proposed code

```
#include <stdio.h>  // sscanf(), sprintf()
#include <stdlib.h> // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

#define MAX_NAME_LEN 20

int main( void )
{
    char name[ MAX_NAME_LEN +1 ];
    long long int id;

    char format[20];
    sprintf( format, "%%%d[^=]=%%lld", MAX_NAME_LEN );

    int status = sscanf("tabid=12544787844;123", format, name, &id);
    if( status != 2 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "sscanf failed to extract the two fields\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, sscanf successful

    printf(" name = %s id=%lld\n", name ,id);
    // by convention:
    // returning 0 indicates success,
    // returning 1 indicates a failure
    return 0;
}
```